# Python: How to get image dimensions from SVG url?

Tags: python, svg, dimensions

I'm looking to get SVG images from an URL via Python. I have tried below script which works for non-SVG images, but I struggle to find a suitable solution for SVGs:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = 'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3488/4051378654_238ca94313.jpg'

img_data = requests.get(url).content    
im = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
print (im.size)
```

Comment: You may find this useful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624831/processing-svg-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PIL to read SVGs (refer to [their docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html) for compatible file formats).

You can use [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to load it. This is as SVGs are vectors that can be parsed as an XML.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import BytesIO

import requests

url = "https://placeholder.pics/svg/300"

img_data = requests.get(url).content
tree = ET.parse(BytesIO(img_data))

width, height = tree.getroot().attrib["width"], tree.getroot().attrib["height"]
print(f"Width: {width} \nHeight: {height}")
```